# Call a function with parameters in JavaScript append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to call a function with parameters in a jQuery `append` method and want to pass a variable named `image` but I keep getting syntax error even when I pass a static value

```
$("#officialDiv").append("<a onclick='remove('" + image + "');' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'></a>");
```

or static

```
$("#officialDiv").append("<a onclick='remove('test');' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'></a>");

function remove(file) {
}
```

below a screenshot of the error

[image]

Comment: What is `image`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your HTML string is breaking on `'`. You need to escape the quotes.

```
$("#officialDiv").append("<a onclick=\"remove(\'" + image + "\');\" class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Link</a>");
```

Should work fine.

**Demo**

```js
var image = "some_data";
$("#officialDiv").append("<a onclick=\"remove(\'" + image + "\');\" class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Link</a>");

function remove(a){
  console.log(a+" is removed");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="officialDiv"></div>
```

Comment: i already tried it and it did not work i keep getting this error `JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 7 in (unknown source location)\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error`

Comment: @User7291 you sure this is the line causing this error?

Comment: @User7291 there was minor issue. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the issue is probably within the `image` variable.

That said, we can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to reduce the quotes confusion.

```
$("#officialDiv").append(`<a onclick="remove(${image});" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Image</a>`);
```

Here's a working example:

```js
var image = "myImage";

$("#officialDiv").append(`<a onclick="remove('${image}');" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Image</a>`);

const remove = function(name) {
  alert(name);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="officialDiv"></div>
```

Comment: it did not work i keep getting Invalid character error

Comment: Yes, I believe the issue is in the `image` variable. You'll need to share the `image` variable with us.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, all the above solutions were not accomplished my requirement.

```
$('.my-list').append('<a href="javascript:openFile(\''+ dataId +'\')"><li class="list-group-item">'+ itemName +'</li></a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test = 'test';
  $("#officialDiv").append("<a onclick='remove(test)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>click me</a>");

  function remove(file) {
   alert(file);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='officialDiv'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

```
var anchor = $("<a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>click me</a>");
anchor.on('click', function () {
    remove(image)
});

$("#officialDiv").append(anchor);

function remove(file) {
    alert(file)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could untie the behavior through an event handler thus removing the issue (additional benefit you get is cleaner, reusable code):

```
<a onclick="onRemoveClick()" ... >
```

---

```
function remove(value) { ... } 
function onRemoveClick() { remove('image'); }
```